# Max width of a "line" view

Tags: java, android, android-view

I'm using a view with only 10dp height, so it just looks like a line.

If my layout_width is greater than a certain number (for example if I set layout_width=900dp), the view doesn't take the width... It seems that there is a max width for a view.
Does anyone know ?

Thanks.
Yan.

EDIT : Sorry, here's my xml layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" >

<View
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="900dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:transformPivotX="5dp"
    android:rotation="45"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT 2 : Here's the result. Why the view can't go further ?
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/40/1411963572-screenshot-2014-09-28-22-36-32.png

Comment: Parent view width limit?

Comment: Add your XML to the question

Comment: Set the View's width to match_parent as well.

Comment: I don't want the view to have the width of it's parent, i've edited with a screenshot of the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it's width and height are limited by the parents bounds, if you didn't rotate it you'll see that it just takes the parents width.

> A View object's measured width and measured height values must respect
>   the constraints imposed by the View object's parents. This guarantees
>   that at the end of the measure pass, all parents accept all of their
>   children's measurements.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html)

If what you want is to draw a rotated line, you can consider doing so directly with a custom view. Follow [this](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html) to get a head start

Comment: Thanks for this answer, very useful. If i put a click listener on my custom view, will the event be activate on all the surface of my canvas ?